# Schengen visa apply in UK

Tags: visas, schengen

I am a UK citizen married to a Filipina.  We will be going to the UK soon.  My wife has a UK visit visa and we plan to visit other EU countries.  Does my wife need a Schengen visa and if she does can she apply for one while in the UK?.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, she should get a Schengen visa.  She should normally apply where she resides, so if you can do that, you should.  However, as the family member of an EU citizen (you), she should also be able to get a visa in the UK.  The problem is that you might be hard-pressed to find a consulate that will agree with that statement.

In any event, the visa should be free of charge and issued quickly.

If you're planning to visit Europe by train or ferry, you can try your luck without a visa, but it's a little risky.

For more information, have a look at the [freedom of movement directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) and, if you'd rather avoid slogging through the legal text, the [summary](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=LEGISSUM%3Al33152).